# MVC C# PagedList - PagedListPager passing array of int as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I don't know how to pass an array of int.
Lets see my code...

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("Index", new
{

    pagina,
    codOccu = ViewBag.codOccu, // the array of int
    nomeEmp = ViewBag.Empresas,
    dtAbert = ViewBag.DataIni,
    dtFinal = ViewBag.DataFim,
    codStatus = ViewBag.codStatus,
    codUsu = ViewBag.CodUsu,
    codSet = ViewBag.CodSet,
    order = ViewBag.order

}))
```

and the query string result looks like http://localhost:8080/Atendimento?pagina=2&codOccu=System.Int32%5B%5D&codStatus=0&codUsu=0&codSet=0&order=1

i need a way to transform codOccu=System.Int32%5B%5D& to
codOccu=123&codOccu=1234&codOccu=12345

Comment: You cannot do that using `Url.Action()` - the method generates the name/value pair using the `.ToString()` of each value

Comment: and what can i do?

Comment: You would have to build the url manually using javascript